# Time series on folium map

Tags: python, dataframe, maps, folium

I have a dataframe that denotes events that occured in particular locations.

I am aware that folium does not allow dynamic display of the appearance of the events so I was thinking about basically iterate through the dates and save a png of each folium map created.

Unfortunately I am mentally stuck in a 2 part problem:

1) how to loop through a ranges of dates (for example one map for each month)

2) an appropriate way to save the generated images for each loop.

This is a dataframe sample for this example:

```
since = ['2019-07-05', '2019-07-17', '2014-06-12', '2016-03-11']

lats = [38.72572, 38.71362, 38.79263, 38.71931]

longs = [-9.13412, -9.14407, -9.40824, -9.13143]

since_map = {'since' : pd.Series(since), 'lats' : pd.Series(lats), 'longs' : pd.Series(longs)}

since_df = pd.DataFrame(since_map)
```

I was able to create the base map:

```
lat_l = 38.736946
long_l = -9.142685

base_l = folium.Map(location=[lat_l,long_l], zoom_start=12)
neigh = folium.map.FeatureGroup()
```

And add some of the markers to the folium map:

```
for lati, longi in zip(since_df.longs, since_df.lats):
    neigh.add_child(folium.CircleMarker([longi, lati], radius = 2, color = 'blue', fill = True))

base_l.add_child(neigh)
```

I am struggling to visualize how to loop through ranges of the dates and save each file. From what I saw here:
https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/35 I actually have to open the saved html and then save it as png for each image.

If you could point me to an example or documentation that could demonstrate how this can be accomplished I would be very appreciative.

If you think I am overcomplicating it or you have a better alternative to what I am thinking I have an open ear to suggestions.

Thank you for your help.